# CSV export in php - csv row as a variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, export-to-csv

I want to export a data into CSV file using PHP Laravel.

I used every row as a variable and add to csv at last. It helps me to create custom CSV file column header, so I must follow this rule.

What I have done is this-

```
$tweets = DB::select(DB::raw($query));

    foreach ($tweets as $row)
    {
        $row = get_object_vars($row);
        // iterate over each tweet and add it to the csv

        $output .=  implode(",",
                            array(
                                $row['completion_date'],
                                $row['site_id'],
                                $row['country'],
                                $row['state'],
                                $row['city'],
                                $row['active_ipp'],
                                $row['description_of_project'],
                                $row['total_excess_furniture']
                                )
                            ); // append each row
        $output .="\n";     //Adding New Line
    }

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename="'.Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString().'.csv"',
    );
    return Response::make(rtrim($output, "\n"), 200, $headers);
```

It is working with some errors.

The errors are, when there is a comma in the object string, it does not work perfectly.

So, I can't use *implode* I think.

Is there any other solution for adding CSV row as a variable like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something along the lines of:

```
$items = [
    [
        'field1' => 'string with " quotes',
        'field2' => 'string without commas',
    ],
    [
        'field1' => 'string without quotes',
        'field2' => 'string, with, commas',
    ],
];

ob_start();
$buffer = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
foreach($items as $item) {
    fputcsv($buffer, [
        $item['field1'],
        $item['field2'],
    ]);
}
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

[`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) will deal with commas or quotes in your variables. Instead of writing the output to a file, you can send the output to a buffer and store it to a variable using `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean`.

Comment: NO, I have found my solution.

So, I am posting the solution of my own

Comment: @AbrarJahin This solution is better than yours - it won't break.